# Disabling OpenMP when Profiling Enabled

Tags: c, macros, profiling, openmp

When profiling my C code, I would like to disable/reduce the number of OMP threads to 1. After a brief search, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847900/disable-openmp-in-nice-way). I would therefore decided to do something like

```
#ifdef foo
    #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif
```

where `foo` is a macro that is true if the `-pg` flag is set when compiling with GCC.

My question then is, what is the value of `foo` and will this method now allow me to get sensible profiling information (by forcing OpenMP to just use one thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to change the number of threads for OpenMP is during program launch with the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS. To get a single-threaded execution of a.out:

```
$> OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out
```

This should return sensible data for profiling. If you completely remove OpenMP, you will be somewhat changing your application so profiling may not be as relevant.

Comment: Or even (but not as portable as `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`)  `taskset -c 0 ./a.out`, to limit CPU cores, available to the omp runtime.