# Switch on/off openmp using macros

Tags: c++, macros, openmp

I want to switch on/off openmp parallel for loops, in specific parts of my code, where as parallelization in other parts will remain intact. Also I do not want to change the source code of that parts every time, so tried some macro hack like following.

```
#ifdef USE_PARALLEL
  #define USE_OPENMP_FOR #pragma omp parallel for
#else
  #define USE_OPENMP_FOR
#endif
```

So that in the source code, I could simply use...

```
USE_OPENMP_FOR
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i ) {
  // some stuffs
}
```

And define the macro `USE_PARALLEL` in `main.cpp` file if I need those parallel loops.

But unfortunately this does not work at all. I know the problem is in   `#define QIC_LIB_OPENMP_FOR #pragma omp parallel for` line. But could not find any solution.

Is there any way to solve this problem, with or without the macro hack?

EDIT::
This question is different from [disable OpenMP in nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847900/disable-openmp-in-nice-way) as I wanted to switch off openmp in specific parts, not for the whole program.
As suggested by **Jarod42** and **Anedar**, `_Pagma("...")` solved my problem.

Comment: Look at [pragma-in-define-macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/pragma-in-define-macro) : `_Pragma`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I got the answer.

Comment: Maybe call `omp_set_num_threads(1);` before your loop to switch off? You also could use this approach with macros. Just an idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable OpenMP in nice way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847900/disable-openmp-in-nice-way)

Comment: @mustafagonul No, it is not. As I wanted to switch off openmp in specific parts, not for the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

You basically can't use `#pragma` inside a `#define`, but you can use the pragma operator as `_pragma("omp parallel for")` inside a macro definition.

If this is not supported by your compiler, this should work:

```
#ifdef USE_PARALLEL
    #define USE_OPENMP_FOR omp parallel for
#else
    #define USE_OPENMP_FOR
#endif

#pragma USE_OPENMP_FOR
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i ) {
  // some stuffs
}
```

Which will just resolve to an empty `#pragma` if `USE_PARALLEL` is not defined.

Comment: Be aware that under gcc with the -Wall flag, this will fire the -Wunknown-pragmas warning.

Comment: `_Pragma(" ")` works well with gcc and clang. Though I don't know if it will work with icc or msvc. But the second solution did not work, it is giving `-Wunknown-pragmas` warning even with `USE_PARALLEL` defined .

Comment: _Pragma is standard C99. It certainly works with icc.