Omp for loops called eventually from omp single region possible?
I'm having a OMP parallel region already open and, depending on some measurements from the past, want to decide if I'm executing a function in parallel or serially.
The function itselve contains omp for loops and omp single, thus barriers.
There is the easy way to dublicate the function, one for parallel execution, one for serial execution. But that's what I want to omit.
Is there a way to achieve this?
I guess I can do it by extensive preprocessor magic, but then the code gets messy enough to not do it...
Here is an code example:
void callMethod()
{
  #pragma omp for 
  for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    std::cout<<"Hello from thread " << omp_get_thread_num() <<" and iter "<<k<<std::endl;
  }
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a = 1000;
if (argc > 2)
    a= (int)argv[1];

 #pragma omp parallel
 {
    if (a < 4)
    {
      callMethod();
    }
    else
    {
      #pragma omp single
      {
        callMethod();
      }
    }
  }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847900/how-to-disable-openmp-directives-in-a-nice-way

While it is often recommended to create big parallel regions to avoid thread creation overheads, modern implementations tend to hold onto their threads either way.  In contrast to the single construct, the parallel construct has an if clause that would make this code much nicer. I.e. #pragma omp parallel if(a < 4) callMethod();

Single and for are both work-sharing constructs. You cannot nest them.

Note that #pragma omp for has no effect outside a #pragma omp parallel section so you can call the same function outside it to run it serially. The solution of paleonix is the cleanest one though, in some rare cases, it can be better just to use a if(...) { omp parallel + callMethod() } else { callMethod(); } because it has a smaller overhead.

Is this hepls?

Finally, I ended up by a semi-elegant way: I put the code to call in parallel and serial to an extra file and use some pre-processor defines to handle the omp statements.
This omits code duplication and keeps the code half-way readable:
//------------------------
//FILE callMethod.hpp:

local_pragma_omp_for()
  for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
  {
    std::cout<<"Hello from thread " << omp_get_thread_num() <<" and iter "<<k<<std::endl;
  }
//FILE callMethod.hpp:
//------------------------

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = 1000;
  if (argc > 2)
    a= (int)argv[1];

  #define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
  
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    if (a < 4)
    {
        #define local_pragma_omp_for() DO_PRAGMA(omp for)
        #include "callMethod.hpp"
        #undef local_pragma_omp_for
    }
    else
    {
      #pragma omp single
      {
        #define local_pragma_omp_for()  // empty, to no write the statement
        #include "callMethod.hpp"
        #undef local_pragma_omp_for
      }
    }
  }
}


I think, you need to add a definition #define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x). Also the macro local_pragma_omp_single seems wrong. Edit queue are full, so just leaving a comment here.

Thanks for the hint, @Joachim. I updated the code snippet
